# In how many ways can 4 males and 4 females sit together in a round table with such that there are exactly 3 males who are seated next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, combinations

I have tried using this method:
first I took 4C3 to choose 3 men to be seated together, then I multiplied by 3! for the 3 men to switch among themselves. After which I grouped the 3 men into one unit. Counting the other 4 women and the remaining 1 men, I should have 6 units. Since this is a round table, I took (6-1)! to arrange this 6 units. I realised that this gives the possibility of including the case where 3 and 4 men could be seating next to each other since that remaining 1 men can be seating next to one of the 3 men in the rotation, so I subtracted the case where there are exactly 4 men who sits next to each other. However, I do not get the answer. Can anyone advise?

below is my working:
$4C3 \times 3! \times (6-1)!-(5-1)! \times 4! = 2304$. The correct answer is $1728$. I tried other methods and I got the answer but I don't understand why this does not work.

Comment: is there somewhere you did not understand in my solution ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the table is circular we can use the group of three men as a reference point, after which there are just three possibilities for the position of the fourth man – one, two or three women between him and the nearest man to his left (this can be counted manually). Thus the $(6-1)!-(5-1)!$ should be just $3$ instead, and all other factors are correct, leading to $1728$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach you can take.

Take the quietest man and seat him first and then seat women in $4!$ ways. Now the remaining $3$ men must be seated together between any two adjacent women - there are $3$ such spaces between women.

Finally arrange men in $4!$ ways.

So the answer is $ \displaystyle 4! \cdot 3 \cdot 4! = 1728$

Answer (score 1):

For your subtracted off case (where four men are seated together), the fourth man could be left or right of the group of three men designated to be seated together. So you need to double your subtracted off term.

Comment: So by doing 4C3 x 3! x (6-1)!, I am actually counting the case with exactly 4 men sitting next to each other twice?

Comment: Yes, because you are considering the three designated together men and the fourth man as separate blocks.

Comment: Ok. Could you elaborate on this? It is quite hard to imagine.

Comment: You have $6$ groups: $3$ men designated to sit together ($1$ group); and $4$ separate women; and $1$ additional man. If you are looking at cases where the $1$ man is sitting next to the three men; there are two ways it can occur: single man to the left of the three men; or single man to the right of the three men. Each of these cases is undesirable and needs to be subtracted off.

Comment: I understand the part where that 1 men could be on the left and right of the 3 men but when I subtract by (5-1)! x 4! wouldn't I be subtracting both cases away? why do I have to subtract it twice?

Comment: In your term of $(5-1)!\cdot 4!$, the $4!$ is coming from the ways to order the four women. The $(5-1)!$ is coming from ordering one group of $4$ men and the $4$ individual women (the $-1$ is for the fact that the seating is circular). But the group of four men could be arranged in two different ways: (grouped men)(single man) or (single man)(grouped men).

Answer (score -1):

Your method is correct , but it is $\color{blue}{\text{deficient}}$ ! As you realize , it is asked that $\color{red}{\text{exactly}}$ one three consecutive men , but your solution gives us $\color{red}{\text{at least}}$ one three consecutive men.So , you need to use the formula of $\color{green}{\text{GENERALIZED VERSION OF P.I.E}}$

$\color{purple}{\text{Lemma:}}$ For each $1 \leq m \leq t$ , the number of elements in S that satify $\color{blue}{exactly}$ $m$ of the conditions $c_1, c_2,...,c_t$ is given by $$E_m=S_m -\binom{m+1}{1}S_{m+1}+\binom{m+2}{2}S_{m+2}-\binom{m+3}{3}S_{m+3}+.......+(-1)^{t-m}\binom{t}{t-m}S_{t}$$

In our question our case is three consecutive men sitting together and it is asked for exactly one case ,so $m=1$ , and $t=2$ because there are at most $2$ case where $3$ consecutive men.Then , $$E_1=S_1 -\binom{1+1}{1}S_{2}$$

$E_1= \binom{4}{3}3!\times(6-1)!$ ,as you calculated

$E_2= 4!\times 4!$ ,as you calculated

Now , by using the lemma : $$E_1=\binom{4}{3}3!\times(6-1)! - \color{red}{2}\times 4!\times 4!= \color{blue}{1728} $$

Comment: @amWhy i am not a native speaker ,so these types of errors may happen.You might have corrected it by a simple edition or just writing a comment instead of downvoting. What you did is just a disrespect to me. This answer does not deserve to be downvoted..

Comment: I did not downvote.  I am sorry about my comment; yes, I could have edited.  But I did not downvote.  Why did you just disrespect me of disrespect to you. I will delete my comment, but I did nothing here but *comment*.

Comment: @amWhy i am sorry for my wrong interpretion , i just looked at downvoting time and saw that it matched with the time of your comment. I guess it was just a coincide. By the way thanks for edition. Sorry again.. Have a nice day !

Comment: No problem.  I understand.  I should have merely edited from the get go.  Nice work, by the way!

Comment: @amWhy thank you :)